# Condition of Network Disconnection

Tags: c, api, curl

Is there a way to find out the condition of a network disconnection without using these two API calls?

```
//bytes/sec
curl_easy_setopt(object, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, dl_lowspeed_bytes);

//seconds while below low spped limit before aborting
curl_easy_setopt(object, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, dl_lowspeed_time);
```